# Error code not working

Tags: hdl

Hello I am trying to implement the gate MiniALU but the howard simulator give me this error: "has no source pin". I would be happy if you can help me solve this.

my code-

```
CHIP MiniALU {
IN  
    x[16], y[16],  // 16-bit inputs        
    zx, // zero the x input?
    zy, // zero the y input?
    f;  // compute  out = x + y (if f == 1) or out = x & y (if == 0)

OUT 
    out[16]; // 16-bit output

PARTS:

// Zero the x input and y input
Mux16(a[0..15]=x, b[0..15]=false, sel=zx, out[0..15]=x1);
Mux16(a[0..15]=y, b[0..15]=false, sel=zy, out[0..15]=y1);
// Perform f
And16(a[0..15]=x2, b[0..15]=y2, out[0..15]=xandy);
Add16(a[0..15]=x2, b[0..15]=y2, out[0..15]=xaddy);
Mux16(a[0..15]=xandy, b[0..15]=xaddy, sel=f, out[0..15]=out);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are connecting x2 and y2 to the inputs of And16 and Add16 but x2 and y2 are not defined anywhere.

You need to replace x2 and y2 with x1 and y1 in the connections to And16 and Add16.

Answer (score 0):

Correct code:

```
Mux16(a=x, b=false, sel=zx, out=x1);

Mux16(a=y, b=false, sel=zy, out=y1);


And16(a=x1, b=y1, out=xandy);

Add16(a=x1, b=y1, out=xaddy);

Mux16(a=xandy, b=xaddy, sel=f, out=out);
```

Your problem was that you wrote *y2* and *x2* instead of *y1* and *x2*.

Also, there is not need in *[0..15]*

Answer (score -1):

You wrote:
And16(a[0..15]=**x2**, b[0..15]=**y2**, out[0..15]=xandy);
Add16(a[0..15]=**x2**, b[0..15]=**y2**, out[0..15]=xaddy);

instead of:
And16(a[0..15]=**x1**, b[0..15]=**y1**, out[0..15]=xandy);
Add16(a[0..15]=**x1**, b[0..15]=**y1**, out[0..15]=xaddy);